# I connected my flutter chat app with firebase now when I run my app on my android emulator get this message

Tags: flutter

W/DynamiteModule( 4488): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
W/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler( 4488): callback not found for CALLBACK_AVAILABLE message
I/DynamiteModule( 4488): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 4488): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler( 4488): callback not found for CALLBACK_AVAILABLE message

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to add the path_provide package in your pub.spec library.